# Audio disruption when trying to play any sound

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

PC: Alienware 17 r3

The problem I'm facing is that any sound coming from my PC sounds disrupted (I don't know if this is exactly the adjective to use in this case). I've been trying to solve this problem for a while but I haven't found a solution yet.

I don't know too much about drivers so I've just tried to change options in `alsamixer` or to reload `pulseaudio` which are the main way people solve this problem in forums, it hasn't worked for me though.

This is my output from `lspci | grep -i audio`:

```bsh
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

I know that for solving this problem it's needed more information so feel free to ask for it.

Edit:

Ubuntu version: 20.04

Comment: Start with what version of Ubuntu and are you using internal speakers or some kind of external setup?

Comment: @David I'm sorry. Ubuntu version: 20.04 and I'm using my laptop internal speakers